# Q: Cytoscape 3.4 How to import several attributes for all nodes and how to differentially represent them

Tags: node.js, cytoscape

I have already imported my whole dataset, around 6k nodes and 300k interactions, managed to format all the edges according to their type of interaction and now I am trying to import the metabolism of each gene into the network as node attributes. However some genes are involved in different metabolisms, so the idea would be to divide each node into n parts, where n is the number of metabolisms that gene is involved and then use each unique color for each metabolism.

With this I'm experiencing some issues, specifically when I import the attributes somehow my node table shifts and loses all the original formatting, i.e. some source nodes become target nodes. I am also having some troubles in figuring out the best way to import several attributes for the same gene without having to repeat that node. For example, Gene 1 is involved in Metab 1, Metab 2 and Metab 3, is there a way to include these 3 Metabs in a single line/cell and then use this information divide the node, or do I need to create 3 entries for each metabolism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking for and provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not working with code, so the minimal example would be not necessary here.
What I'm asking is: I want to upload an attribute table to my nodes in Cytoscape with the information regarding their metabolism functions. However there are several nodes with more than 1 metabolism, that way I have to create more columns for each additional metabolism. That, however doesn't allow me to use the node formatting options for all metabolism since they are in different columns. Is there a way to go around this?